# asp.net 5 ambiguous reference match

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты

Ситуация следующая: в солюшене 2 проекта (основной asp.net 5 и второй для юнит-тестов). В проекте для юнит-тестов добавил ссылку на  основной проект. При попытке обратиться к классам основного проекта выскакивает сабж. Как это лечить? 
BlogPost - класс основного проекта. Class1 - тестового.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено. Это была проблема с решарпером( конечно же, это ведь бета-версия!). Когда я его отключил, предупреждение ушло и vs2015 приняла этот код, как валидный.